# Issue during installation of web based project installer cab file with InstallShield

Tags: installshield, cab

I have created a web based project and I have to install an ActiveX Control through web by a CAB file.

When I build my InstallShield Web project installer, it generate MSI package and a CAB file. 
I have to register a DLL in CAB file.

If I install the MSI package locally, it works fine: it installed the activeX and registered the DLL.

But when I place the CAB file on the server and call that file remotely through web, it failed to register the DLL and it is not installed properly.

I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like static paths or a different type to system for your server. So he can not find the real path to an DLL.

For Information about this Topic read:

[Nice Sybase Documentation about it](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00124_0800/html/moblfeat/CHDIAIGG.htm)

[Nice Guide for creating CAB Files](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html)

[MSDN Documentation for INF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924371.aspx)

From MSDN Documentation:
"...For this reason, if multiple files within a .cab are given the same name but different install directories, only one of the files will be installed in all locations. To work around this behavior, be sure to use unique names for all files within a single .cab file...."

and look up this Keywords:

SourceDisksNames/DestinationDirs

Hope that will fix it! :-)